# How to display contents(two labels and one image view) in cell from two different NSMutableArray in two different sections.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to parse  xml and  show the title, description and image in table cell.

I did following code, but if image is not available, then also garbage image is displaying on cell.

I did code to hide it but image view not hiding.

Also I set frame to zero values but image view with garbage image is displaying:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (section == 0) {
        return [appDelegate.TrendDataArray count];
    }else {
        return [appDelegate.MyDataArray count];
    }

}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    if(section == 0)

        return @" Trending ";

    else

        return @" Live Feeds ";

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UILabel *lblTitle;
    UILabel *lbldescription;
    UIImageView *imgViewTemp;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [lblTitle setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [lblTitle setNumberOfLines:2];
        lblTitle.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:FONT]];
        lblTitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [lblTitle setTag:1];

        lbldescription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [lbldescription setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [lbldescription setNumberOfLines:3];
        lbldescription.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [lbldescription setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:FONT2]];
        lbldescription.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        [lbldescription sizeToFit];
        [lbldescription setTag:2];

        imgViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [imgViewTemp setTag:3];


        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbldescription];

        //[imgViewTemp release];
        [lblTitle release];
        [lbldescription release];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        appDelegate=(AppDelegate_iPhone  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        objXmlParse_Attributes= [appDelegate.TrendDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        appDelegate=(AppDelegate_iPhone  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        objXmlParse_Attributes= [appDelegate.MyDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }


    NSString *text = objXmlParse_Attributes.CommenUrlTitle;
    text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSString *text2 = objXmlParse_Attributes.CommenUrlDescription;
    text2 = [text2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(WIDTH - (MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:FONT] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize size2 = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:FONT2] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", objXmlParse_Attributes.CommenUrlImage];

    //imgViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    //[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"]



    if([link isEqualToString:@"No image"] || [link isEqualToString:@"no image"]){
        link = @"";
        if ([link isEqualToString:@""]) {

            imgViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];

        //[imgViewTemp release];

        lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        [lblTitle setText:text];
        [lblTitle setFrame:CGRectMake(MARGIN+3,MARGIN, WIDTH-110+83,MIN(size.height,30))];

        lbldescription = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
        [lbldescription setText:text2];
        [lbldescription setFrame:CGRectMake(MARGIN+3,MARGIN + MIN(size.height,30),WIDTH-110+83,MIN(size2.height,40))];
     }
    }
    else{

        //imgViewTemp = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
        imgViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7,11,73,60)];
        [imgViewTemp setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link] placeholderImage:nil];
        //image1.hidden=FALSE;

        lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        [lblTitle setText:text];
        [lblTitle setFrame:CGRectMake(MARGIN + 83, MARGIN, WIDTH-110,MIN(size.height,30))];

        lbldescription = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
        [lbldescription setText:text2];
        [lbldescription setFrame:CGRectMake(MARGIN + 83, MARGIN + MIN(size.height,30),WIDTH-110,MIN(size2.height,40))];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgViewTemp];

    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just search for tutorial to make table. Dont ask such query in this portion, there is a lot of example for `UITableView`...I hope you understand.

Comment: i solved using this solution
if(section ==0){
      //here my code for adding labels and image from array1
}
if(section ==1){
      //here my code for adding labels and image from array2
}